# PhpSpreadsheet conditional formatting cell (fill)

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have set theese conditions:

```
$objConditionalRed->setConditionType(conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS);
$objConditionalRed->setOperatorType(conditional::OPERATOR_LESSTHAN);
$objConditionalRed->addCondition('50');
$objConditionalRed->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(fill::FILL_SOLID);
$objConditionalRed->getStyle()->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
$objConditionalRed->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Font formating works well (even if I change getFill to getFont and color font, it works), however, cell would not fill if condition is met, what might be wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the problem was, that I needed to use getEndColor() instead of getStartColor(),
if someone knows, why this one should be used, will be pleased to hear.
T.Y.